# How to create an n x 2 grid programmatically in Android Java code?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, screen-size, grid-layout

I have defined a custom view, as a Java class, and now I want to put them in a layout, programmatically.

I can define a layout structure like this :

```
<LinearLayout> <!-- vertical, main container -->

    <LinearLayout> <!-- 1st horizontal (consists of 2 columns (items) ) -->
        <CustomView /> <!-- 1 -->
        <CustomView /> <!-- 2 -->       
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout> <!-- 2nd horizontal (consists of 2 columns (items) ) -->
        <CustomView /> <!-- 1 -->
        <CustomView /> <!-- 2 -->
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- ..... -->
    <LinearLayout> <!-- nth horizontal (consists of n columns (items) ) -->
        <CustomView /> <!-- 1 -->
        <CustomView /> <!-- 2 -->
    </LinearLayout>




</LinearLayout><!-- vertical container -->
```

but when I delete one of the custom views, it remains ugly. Suppose n=3 and I removed custom view number 4. I have :

```
1 2
3 
5 6
```

which does not look good, they should "fill the leading space" like this:

```
1 2
3 5
6
```

How should I achieve such a thing?

And please note that I construct the `CustomView`s in Java code (not in XML)

I have tried getting the screen size, dividing it by n, and assign the value as the `LayoutParams.width` of the custom view.

But getting the screen size in dp's is not a very accurate thing, according to some questions in StackOverflow.

So how should I create a grid layout programmatically ?

Comment: Have you considered using a `GridView`? That does everything you describe here. If you have, then perhaps you could elaborate on why you dismissed it, so we better understand your intentions. Also, `2 x 3 != n x n`. ;)

Comment: I thought that GridView was added in a later API Level. omg is this API Level 1 ? and yes, you are right, I formulized it wrong :) I'm actually trying to create an nx2 grid. Updated the question. hope it is right now :)

Comment: You may be confusing `GridLayout` and `GridView`. The former was originally added with ICS, but is now also available for API level 7+ thanks to the support library (v7). Anyways, I'm babbling, because you're probably going to be interested in `GridView` more.

Comment: Yes that's it :) I've never realized there is a Gridview

Answer (score 0):

Why you are not using GridView in this case?

You could reduce the size of GridView depending on the items you are having in your Collections as,

```
int NUM_COLUMNS = 5;
double NUM_ROWS = items.size() / NUM_COLUMNS; // calculate no. of rows.
double calculateHeight;
if(items.size() % 5 == 0){ // 5, 10, 15, 20...
    calculateHeight = ((NUM_ROWS) * height of required gridview row) + 50; 
                                                        // adding 50 for spacing.
}
else{ // 1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,11...
    calculateHeight = ((NUM_ROWS + 1) *  height of required gridview row) + 50; 
                                                        // adding 50 for spacing.
}
mGridView.getLayoutParams().height = (int) calculateHeight; // setting 
                                                     the final Height of GridView
```